# Gatsby develop and Gatsby info both returning errors

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I don't quite know what happened to my build, Currently `gatsby develop` is returning `TypeError: Cannot read property 'allMarkdownRemark' of undefined` pointing to this file

```
gatsby-node.js:19 graphql.then.results
C:/Users/Anders/sites/gatsby-netlify-cms/gatsby-node.js:19:20
```

and `gatsby info` is returning after it returns info about the project `error The system cannot find the path specified.`

Here is the `gatsby-node.js` file

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    graphql(`
      {
        allMarkdownRemark {
          edges {
            node {
              frontmatter {
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `).then(results => {
      results.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
          path: `/posts${node.frontmatter.slug}`,
          component: path.resolve('./src/components/postLayout.js'),
          context: {
            slug: node.frontmatter.slug,
          },
        })
      })
      resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

I don't quite understand what is going on, I rolled back to changes that were working fine a minute ago, and now getting this weird error. I have tried upgrading node, I have tried reinstalling the gatsby cli. I am stuck. Thanks in advance.

Also including my package.json in case there is incompatibilities

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "description": "Gatsby default starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.9.2",
    "gatsby": "^2.0.53",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.0.22",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.0.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "^3.0.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.16",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.0.15",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.0.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.0.4",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.10",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.1.15",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.9",
    "netlify-cms": "^2.3.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-spring": "^6.1.10",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.15.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  }
}
```

Gatsby -v returns `2.4.7` and I am running node v10.14.2

Here is my gatsby-config file

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Project Name',
    content: 'your name is weird',
    siteUrl: 'https://zealous-wright-0d00e0.netlify.com',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-styled-components',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: 'project-name',
        short_name: 'project-name',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#663399',
        theme_color: '#663399',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/logo.png', // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.app/offline
    'gatsby-plugin-offline',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/team`,
        name: 'team',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
        name: 'images',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-remark',
    'gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms',
  ],
}
```

and I have a file in the `gatsby-source-filesystem` at `src/team/riels-first-post.md`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a very stupid bug, inside my markdown file there was no `slug` attribute which was being referenced across my code. This is what it should of looked like

```
---
title: Riel's First post
bio: I am a monkey with a dog
slug: "test"
---
Testing
```

Comment: It was more about how I had my gatsby code was configured, a slug was necessary in how I was referencing stuff.

Comment: I would not recommend using the slug in your frontmatter. The slug is already an existing thing you can get with graphql. You should look at a gatsby blog example to look how it is done. [Here](https://github.com/Oscarteg/blog/blob/master/gatsby-node.js) is an example how I did it

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your gatsby-config file but, judging by the error, I would say that your node file failed to find any markdown files which results in an undefined `results.data`.

In your gatsby config file there should be a directive similar to this one:

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
        name: `posts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/static/content/collections/posts`,
    },
}
```

The above code instructs gatsby to look for markdown files in the specified path so make sure you have this directive inside your config and that the path contains at least one valid markdown file.

Comment: I added gatsby config file above I already had everything you are suggesting needed to be there including the markdown files. The weird thing is this was working fine at some point and then all of a sudden it stopped and I rolled back my changes to a working commit and still the same error.

Comment: Did you also deleted the `.cache` folder and `public/`?

Comment: No, should I delete those and rerun Gatsby develop

Comment: My public/static folder is empty, if that matters.